# RJDBC Date Confusion

Tags: sql, r

When running a query from Rstudio to SQL Server, the dates I see in my result sets are off by two days:

```
 drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
   "/etc/sqljdbc_3.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar") 
   conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://blah", "blah", "shhh....")
 #then build a query and run it
 sqlText <- paste("Use Logs;
    SELECT * FROM Log_2011_07_26 with (NOLOCK)
    WHERE CreationDate >= '2011-07-26 13:44:44' AND
     CreationDate <= '2011-07-26 14:04:44' AND
    Server = 'ny-web02'", sep="")
 queryResults <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlText)

 View(queryResults)
```

However, the results all have 2011-07-24 as the date. The correct query is being run as seen by sp_WhoIsActive on the server. The results are what they should be it seems, with the exception of the datetime field (In other words, all the fields line up with the proper results I see in SQL Server Management studio). The time is also accurate -- just the date seems wrong.

Comment: Do you get the same incorrect date values if you run the select statement directly in SSMS?

Comment: @Derek Kromm: No, the date values look fine running the exact same query (as captured by sp_WhoIsActive).

Comment: A shot in the dark, but maybe try a different driver?

Comment: @Joshua: Is there one that works on Linux that will talk to SQL Server that you know of? I was just following a tutorial on r-bloggers (for which you were sited as the source ;-) )

Comment: I've only done it with the driver @JDLong used in the post you reference... my only other idea is maybe there's a time / timezone difference between the SQL server and your Linux box that is causing some kind of issue during the date conversion in R.

Comment: @Joshua: I am in EDT and the Server is UTC, can I tell R to think in UTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database column is a `datetime2` column which apparently something along the chain doesn't understand.

If I select it as `CAST(CreationDate AS DATETIME)` I get the proper date. So I guess the solution is to either select it like that or change the table (unless I hear better).

Answer (score 0):

We're running into the same issue usind the Date type.

We have 4 environments setup.  Dev, SIT, UAT and Prod.  We were using the SQL Server Driver in production because of the automatic fail over capability that the JTDS driver does not have, but JTDS in all Other environments.  We started seeing other minor differences between the drivers so we migrated all other environments (Dev, SIT and UAT) to the MS version of the driver.

For some reason, the SIT environment shows dates off by two days where none of the environments do.

We have too many changes that would trigger a full regression test cycle to use Datetime as a data type.  All things being equal, there must be a minor difference in the environment that is causing this.  Has there been anyone else who has run into this and fixed it?

Note:  I checked my date location settings and they seem to be the same across all environments.

We've also pointed Dev at the SIT database and the Date type came out correctly.  We then tried to point SIT at the Dev database and the dates came out incorrectly.

As far as we can tell all environments are mirror environments of each other and SIT is the only one experiencing this issue.

Comment: Just an update.  We had 2 servers that were images of each other. One returned the date properly and the other was 2 days short.  We discovered that the driver works in the 32 bit version of Java consistently, but the driver is inconsistent with Java 7 64 bit version

Comment: Update:  As it turns out, it seems the issue we are experiencing is related to Java 7 32 bit as well.  We have tested it on many machines and VM's (not to be mistaken with JVM) with Java 6 32 bit and Java 6 64 bit without issue.

Comment: While the info is valuable, I don't think it's an answer. It'd be better to have it as a comment to the original question.